# Windows Workflow Foundation 4.5 (WF45) with ASP.NET 5

Tags: .net, workflow, asp.net-core, workflow-foundation, dnx

I'm researching workflow engine options for an ASP.NET 5 enterprise solution.  When reading about WF45 it appears to be dependent on DLLs and I haven't seen any support for DNX packages mentioned.

Has anyone implemented WF45 with DNX package support?  I know I could use both types of projects but I was hoping to re-use the code in my DNX packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WWF hasn't been ported to .NET Core. You can follow the issue on github here https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/2394

Answer (score 2):

> > Has anyone implemented WF45 with DNX package support?
> >     Yes, I did.  I've hosted WF45 at ASP.Net 5.0 using WorkflowHostingEndpoint.  Works without issues.

Though it probably indeed won't work on "dnxcore50", but it will on "dnx451"

Your project.json file going to contain lines like the following:

```
"frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
        "dependencies": {
        },
        "frameworkAssemblies": {
            "System.Activities": "",
            "System.ServiceModel": "",
            "System.ServiceModel.Activities": "",
            "System.ServiceModel.Web": "",
            "System.Xml": "",
            "System.Xaml": ""
        }
    }
},
```